# $1$D Wave equation complete solution confusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I have a question regarding the $1$D wave equation:
$$ \cfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2} = \cfrac{1}{c^2} \cfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}$$

I have seen in several physics books that its complete solution is:
$$
y(x,t)=f_1(x-ct)+f_2(x+ct)
$$

> I do not understand what $f_1$ and $f_2$ exactly are
>
> i) Since, given some boundary conditions, the solution is an infinite sum of sine and cosine functions, shouldn't each one of those functions ($f_1$ and $f_2$) be an infinite sum of $g_n(x \pm ct)$ functions, for instance, accompanied by arbitrary $c_n$ constants ?
>
> ii) I understand that $f_1$ and $f_2$ satisfy the PDE, but how do we know there should not be another $f_3( ... )$ term with another argument in the $y(x,t)$ expression?

Comment: i) Given the representation of $y$ above, the assumption is that you are solving the PDE for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Otherwise yes, if the set is compact then some particular boundary boundary conditions imply an infinite set of _discrete_ modes and in turn an infinite set of eigenfunctions and constants ii) You can 'factor' the operator to get $$\left( \partial_{t} - c \partial_{x} \right)\left( \partial_{t} + c \partial_{x} \right) y = L_{1} L_{2} y = 0$$ The solution is then a sum of the solutions to $L_{1}y = 0$ and $L_{2}y = 0$.

Comment: @mattos Thank you! So, $f_1$ and $f_2$ could each represent an infinite sum of functions in some cases (boundary conditions mentioned) right?

Answer (score 1):

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are general expressions.  The point of the representation is that the two argument function of $(x,t)$ is the sum of two one argument functions of $(x-ct)$ and $(x+ct)$.